# sharepoint.stackexchange data analysis - 2018

Tags: discussion

This is the third edition of the analysis.

In general trends in 2018 are not so good as in 2016-2017. Especially things have become changing in September 2017 and slowly goes down until now. Do you have any ideas why? For me, it looks like some kind of news or something appeared in fall 2017. Just guessing :)

[THE LINK](https://spblog.net/post/2019/01/08/sharepoint-development-state-in-2018-story-based-on-sharepoint-stackexchange-analysis-with-power-bi)

Comment: Awesome Report, Thanks for sharing ♥

Answer (score 6):

*This post is very opinionated, and should be read as a point of view of the writer and not the community, nor the StackExchange business.*

It's simple. I changed job from being a SharePoint Consultant in July 2018 to be a more general Solution Architect. :-)

Or more importantly, I've felt the need to move away from SharePoint since it's popularity is decreasing, and has been for the last 18 months. There are several reasons to it. One is its now a mature product where very little happen, and you really don't need to develop SharePoint to make it work. That alone decrease consultant hour demands.

Second is that SharePoint is slowly but surely fading away as a service rather than a product. It's brand is weakened, and fewer and fewer users know that they actually run SharePoint. "We got our documents is Office 365, so what do we need SharePoint for?" is not uncommon. To us, it's like saying "Why do we need Nuclear Power Plants when we have Electricity?".

It's sad really, because I'm not done with SharePoint, but one have to put food on the table even ten years from now. And quite frankly, I believe that SharePoint will be long gone by then. So I switched career for the 10th time to do something that will still be there in the future.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, that's really interesting! 
From my POV SharePoint still has a lot of demand, especially Online version. And I don't have a feeling that it will be gone in 10 years. But we'll see. Let's meet here in 10 years :) 
I compare it with Sitecore. I know it's smth different, but the idea is the same. That's a CMS was founded in 2001 and still has a lot of demand and a lot of jobs. SharePoint is somewhat similar, however, it transforms faster and too frequently. And like you mentioned it's more Office 365 now rather than SharePoint.

Comment: @SergeiSergeev I've created a [Doodle for the event in ten years](https://doodle.com/poll/drgszqci72wtwvtu), please join :) On a more serious note, I think we are moving toward a more containerized future where these enormous framework/service pile of code we call SharePoint/SiteCore/EPiServer/Adobe-CMS/any-other-CMS will eventually fall, since they are becoming an obstacle rather than an enabler. But we will see what the future brings :)

Answer (score 3):

Great analysis. Very interesting to see the trends.

To your question on the decline in activity, I agree with @4rchit3xt's comment on the rise of Office 365. With increased Office 365 adoption, there is less need for standalone SharePoint Server. OneDrive and SharePoint are the storage for all of Office 365. However, that's often not obvious to the user, so they may just think of it all as Office 365.

I think the shift in SharePoint development to the SharePoint Framework may also be a contributing factor. By design, SharePoint Framework makes use of common standards so much easier. When you allow developers to use common tools across Microsoft and non-Microsoft development platforms, there's less need to ask specialized questions. Where you used to see a strong need to specialize in SharePoint Development, it's now not as hard to learn.